# Splitting strings in 80%/20% parts

Tags: python, string, list, split

I have a list of strings and I only want to keep the first 80% of text of each string. So, if a string has for example 100 words, I only want to keep the first 80 words. The split function is not suitable for this problem.

What function can I use, while iterating over the list, to achieve this?

Comment: It totally is suitable if you made the effort to use it

Comment: Did look for a long time into this problem and searched on Stackoverflow for possible solutions. However, I did not now / could not find anything that said it could be combined with len this easy.

Comment: Your question ought to reflect the research that you did. This is not a particularly hard problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why isn't it?

```
sentence = "long string lots of words..."
parts = sentence.split()
newsentence = ' '.join(parts[:len(parts)*4//5])
```

Comment: Please don't encourage this sort of question by feeding OP answers, even if they are good answers

Comment: That's a judgement call.  In my view, the task was clear, and the fact that he mentioned `split` says that he did try something, even if he didn't post it.  I don't think this is a clear-cut case of a "bad question", although Lord knows I've seen a lot of those.